# mapping over items in array - react

Tags: reactjs

I have an object like so:

```
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "car",
      "colors": ["white", "black"]
    }
```

I put my object into `data` using useState.
When i try `data.name` the result is "car"
When i try `data.colors` the result is "whiteblack"
But when i try mapping over the colors using:

```
{data.colors.map((color, i) =>
  <span key={i} >{color}</span>
)}
```

Ill get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`
What am I missing?

Comment: can you show how you initialized data

Comment: where are you mapping data.colors data?

Comment: I suppose your data gets into state asynchronously? And you try to map through it in the render, which happens before the data is loaded. If yes, this is causing the error. If no, please share your component logic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One likely reason is that you try to map over data before data is loaded. For example, if you initiate a fetch call to some resource when a component is loaded but also map over the returned object at the same time. In that case, data would be undefined.

A simple fix would be to check if data is undefined before mapping over it.

```
{data && data.colors.map((color, i) =>
  <span key={i} >{color}</span>
)}
```

Comment: I completely forgot I can check if data is already available. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be it's state initializing issue, you could do something like this:

> ```
> const [state, setState] = useState({
>       "id": "",
>       "name": "",
>       "colors": []
>     });
>
> useEffect(() => setState({
>       "id": 1,
>       "name": "car",
>       "colors": ["white", "black"]
>     }), []);
> ```

This will fix your `map of undefined` issue.